# Mongoid OR query syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

This must be asked alot but it is very poorly documented. There is no mention at http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html

I'm trying to check whether a user exists (below is an AND query), how can I change it to an `OR` type query

```
Username.where(:username=>@username, :email=>@email)
```

(Either the email or the username must match).

I have found some pretty complicated ways online including sending a direct javascript (from): http://omarqureshi.net/articles/2010-6-17-using-or-in-mongoid

Surely there must be a simple clear syntax to do this correctly?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yeah, this used to be documented better. Try this:

```
Username.any_of({:username => @username},
                {:email => @email})
```

Answer (score 124):

For the sake of others who end up on this page, the updated syntax is now

```
Username.or({username: @username}, {email: @email})
```

Please refer to the [updated docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/origin/Origin/Selectable#or-instance_method) or [relevant impl](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/criteria/queryable/selectable.rb#L433-L446).

Comment: In scopes you still have to use `any_of` otherwise it will throw a syntax error.

Comment: Link posted doesn't tell anything about `.or` nor `any_of`, please refer [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/criteria/queryable/selectable.rb) to see detailed documentation and implementation

Comment: you can also use self.or in scopes (because `or` is a keyword in ruby)

Answer (score 9):

There is a typo in @miguel-savignano's response. According to Stackoverflow the "edit queue is full", which is why I didn't submit an edit.

Proper syntax:

```
Username.or({username: @username}).or({email: @email})
```

A more concise solution:

```
Username.or({username: @username}, {email: @email})
```

The Mongo selector will resolve to:

```
{"$or"=>[{"username"=>@username}, {"email"=>@email}]}
```

---

I found this question as I was trying to solve for creating "or" queries.

If you are looking to match a string or any one of an array of elements, then you will need to write a Mongoid query with the Mongo '$in' selector.

For example, you have a specific username and an array of emails. You would like to return all results where at least one of the fields matches either the username or one of the emails within the array.

```
@username = "jess"
@emails = ["hi@mail.com", "test@mail.com", "foo@mail.com"]
User.or({username: ""}, {email: {'$in': @emails}})
```

The Mongo selector will resolve to:

```
{"$or"=>[{"first_name"=>""}, {"email"=>{:$in=>["hi@mail.com", "test@mail.com", "foo@mail.com"]}}]}
```

- If you have `Users` with 2 of the 3 emails in your database, then the selector will return a count of 2.
- If you have a `User` with the `username` "jess" and 3 additional `Users` each with one of the given emails, then the selector will return a count of 4.

Answer (score 9):

Also, in Mongoid 5.0, if you still want to use the `where` method, use the following

```
Username.where('$or' => [ { username: @username }, { email: @email } ])
```

this is very useful when you are building a kind of query hash in a dynamic way and you need to keep the `where` method

Answer (score 7):

In Mongoid 5.0, this works for me

```
Username.or({username: @username}).or({email: @email})
```