# Mongoid Query documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm looking into Mongoid Query documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-queries/) and I only see very simple examples like `Band.where(name: "Depeche Mode")`

I would like to see how `.or .and .any_of .any_in` and others work

Where can I find this documentation for mongoid 5+?

Many stackoverflow question ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17747646/1275069)) point to [this link](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html) but that link redirects the first link I posted, where there is nothing about the methods I mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most accurate documentation I could find is inside the code.

See [this link](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/criteria/queryable/selectable.rb)