# Build the hash query from array for mongoid rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have query like this for postgresql:

```
users = users.where(search_string.join(' or '), search: "%# 
{params[:search][:value]}%")
```

But I need to rebuild it for mongoid cos of Error ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))

can someone explain how to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999368/mongoid-or-query-syntax should help

Comment: thx a lot! @engineersmnky