# Equivalent Filter MongoDb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I can't create a rails query with mongoid equivalent to a mongo query.

school.student{"sigae.valid_username.username": { $exists: true}}

How can I convert this query to use in Rails with MongoId?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mongold, but these might help: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-queries/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999368/mongoid-or-query-syntax You could try some of the syntax there, you might be able to call .any? on the result (not sure)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what was the result?

Comment: Add the mongoid documents definitions. It will help with understanding your model structure.